# Read list of items file in Maven

Tags: xml, maven, plugins, iterator, pom.xml

In the `pom.xml` of my Maven project I have a list of items which I use for a loop through the `iterator-maven-plugin`. The list of items looks like:

```
<items>
<item>Script1.sql<item>
<item>Script2.sql<item>
...
<item>Scriptn.sql<item>
</items>
```

However, instead of having the long set of items inside my `pom.xml`, I would like to read them from an xml file as it will make it easier to update. I've seen that in the [documentation of the iterator](http://khmarbaise.github.io/iterator-maven-plugin/iterator-overview.html) there's a way of using [folders](http://khmarbaise.github.io/iterator-maven-plugin/iterator-folder.html), but I haven't found the way to use them for my purpose: to read my list of items from an external text file (it can be an xml, txt, comma separated, etc). If you know a better way to do it, please let me know.

The structure of the project is:

```
    .
│   pom.xml
│
├───db
│   │   list.xml
│   └───migration
│           script1.sql
│           script2.sql
│           script3.sql
│           script4.sql
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   └───java
│   │       └───com
│   │           └───example
│   │               └───app
│   │                       App.java
│   │
│   └───test
│       └───java
│           └───com
│               └───example
│                   └───app
│                           AppTest.java
```